# Series Mark Style Change

Tags: activex, teechart

There is a new requirement from our client. they want the mark to display the value as well as percentage. But currently there is no Option for the same in the Series Marks property page. Is there any work around by which we can show Value along with percentage.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Using *smsLabelPercentValue*, for example:

   ```
   TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Style = smsLabelPercentValue
   ```
2. Customize marks text in the OnGetSeriesMark event, for example:

   ```
   Dim sum As Double

   Private Sub Form_Load()
       TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues
       'TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Style = smsLabelPercentValue

       sum = 0

       For i = 0 To TChart1.Series(0).Count
           sum = sum + TChart1.Series(0).YValues.value(i)
       Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub TChart1_OnGetSeriesMark(ByVal SeriesIndex As Long, ByVal ValueIndex As Long, MarkText As String)
       Dim value As Double
       Dim percent As Double

       value = TChart1.Series(SeriesIndex).YValues.value(ValueIndex)
       percent = (value / sum) * 100

       MarkText = CStr(value) & " " & CStr(percent) & "%"
   End Sub
   ```
3. Use a hybrid solution, manually parsing *MarkText* argument with *smsLabelPercentValue* in OnGetSeriesMark event.

Comment: I have added the event OnGetSeriesMark in my code but not getting a break point in it after doing Mark Visible On. DO i have to add something more to the code.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla in theory, setting marks to visible should suffice. If this doesn't work please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here. You can post your files at http://www.steema.net/upload/

Comment: Hi, The problem which I am facing now is not able to change the value of Mark text my function is OnGetSeriesMark(long SeriesIndex,long ValueIndex,BSTR MarkText)

Comment: @AkshayBhalla can you please send a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: uploaded DraggingPoint.cpp and .h on the site u told.Please replace this file in the example folder of VC++, Dragging point.

Comment: What does third parameter of the event take is it pointer or a reference because if it is a normal string the changes made to it inside this function may not be reflected.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla did you find the solution to the problem?

Comment: No not yet still trying to find out some work around

Comment: Hi Got the solution the third parameter of the event should be VTS_PBSTR.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla I'm glad to hear that. Honestly, I think my answer replied to your initial question. I couldn't be more specific since you didn't mention the exact development environment you were using.